# Manage java game card actions. How?

Tags: java, eclipse

So basically my question is the same as this one:
[Card game with huge amount of cards and complex actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27771699/card-game-with-huge-amount-of-cards-and-complex-actions)

But I don't "speak or understand a word" of C++.
It's my very first big java project and I want to implement a Trading Card Game component.
My problem is: I plan on using 100+ different cards, with different actions. There'll be 4 main types. Within those types, the card's actions are similar but still different.
I thought about making an extra class like

```
public class CardActionDatabase {
    public void card1Action(){}
    public void card2Action(){}
    ....
}
```

But the problem is, I can't invoke/call them within the actual code like

```
(playedcard.getName())Action()
```

since that's impossible in a compiled language.
So basically I'd have to "if" the recent played card with all existing ones, which would be inefficient.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

I've been messing around with card games myself, and there are a few options here. A simple way to do it (though perhaps not the most efficient) is thusly:

First, create an abstract class `Card` that contains common variables and methods, such as `String name` and `public void onPlay()`. Then you might make another abstract subclass for each of your four types.

Then, create subclasses of `Card` for each unique card in your game. These subclasses define `onPlay()` in their own way. Then in your player turn logic, when a player chooses a card, that card's `onPlay` method is called. You can even add stuff like `onDiscard`, `onDestroy`, or `onTurnStart`.

You might also consider creating controller classes between the "Cards" and the "Field/Play Area". For example, you might have a `HandController` class that has public methods `DiscardRandom()`, `Discard(int index)` and `Draw()` which the Cards can use to manipulate the gameplay as they should.

It can become troublesome and complex to manage the chain of calls needed to perform actions appropriately, but strong documentation goes a long way.